# Get the file name using Google file ID

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-drive-api

Is it possible to get the file name using a the ID of a Google file? I was able to gather the ID's, open and download the files, but I want to get the file name as well.

Comment: try looking for title.  Welcome to stack please http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API but wouldn't the [get function](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) return what you want?